# Создание Custom TextBox с автодополнением

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Есть задание - создать TextBox с некоторой логикой автодополнения. Вот код определения расширенного TextBox:

```
public partial class ExtentedTextBox : TextBox
{
    private List<string> _AutoCompleteList = new List<string>()
    {
        "SELECT", "WHERE", "FROM",
        "INSERT", "DELETE", "UPDATE"
    };
    private ListBox _AutoCompleteListBox;

    public ExtentedTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.TextChanged += ExtentedTextBox_TextChanged;
        this.KeyDown += ExTextBox_KeyDown;
        CreateAutocompleteListBox();
    }

    private void CreateAutocompleteListBox()
    {
        _AutoCompleteListBox = new ListBox()
        {
            Left = Left,
            Top = Top + Height,
            Width = 100,
            Height = 75
        };

        _AutoCompleteListBox.Click += AutoCompleteListBox_Click;
        _AutoCompleteListBox.KeyDown += AutoCompleteListBox_KeyDown;
        _AutoCompleteListBox.Visible = false;
        Controls.Add(_AutoCompleteListBox);
    }

    private void AutoCompleteListBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutocompleteFinished();
    }

    private void AutoCompleteListBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var finishCodes = new List<Keys> { Keys.Return, Keys.Space };
        if (finishCodes.Contains(e.KeyCode))
        {
            AutocompleteFinished();
        }
    }

    private string GetLastWord(TextBox txt)
    {
        return (" " + txt.Text).Split(' ').LastOrDefault() ?? "";
    }

    private void ShowAutoCompleteList()
    {
        _AutoCompleteListBox.Left = Left;
        _AutoCompleteListBox.Top = Top + Height + 2;
        var lastWord = GetLastWord(this);

        _AutoCompleteListBox.Items.Clear();
        _AutoCompleteListBox.Items.AddRange(_AutoCompleteList.Where(aw => aw.ToLower().StartsWith(lastWord.ToLower())).ToArray());
        _AutoCompleteListBox.Visible = true;
    }

    private void ExTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // These keys show auto-complete selector
        var activatorCodes = new List<Keys> { Keys.Up, Keys.Down };
        if (activatorCodes.Contains(e.KeyCode))
        {
            SwitchToAutoCompleteList();
        }
    }

    private void SwitchToAutoCompleteList()
    {
        this._AutoCompleteListBox.Focus();
        this._AutoCompleteListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void AutocompleteFinished()
    {
        var lastWord = GetLastWord(this);
        var nextWord = _AutoCompleteListBox.Text;
        Text = Text.Substring(0, Text.Length - lastWord.Length);
        AppendText(nextWord);
        _AutoCompleteListBox.Visible = false;
    }

    private void ExtentedTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowAutoCompleteList();
    }
}
```

После компиляции, кидаю этот кастомный TextBox на форму. Всё хорошо, компиляция происходит успешно, проект запускается. Но при вводе в TextBox логика автодополнения выполняется не так, как требуется.

Ожидаемая логика: при вводе каждого слова, программа предлагает дополнить вводимые слова, как показано на следующем скриншоте - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDFkA.png
То, что есть на самом деле: при вводе любых слов не отображается ComboBox.

Но если использовать вышеуказанную логику для дефолтного TextBox, определив её непосредственно в коде формы, всё будет работать.

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы добавляете листбокс *внутрь* своего текстбокса:

```
Controls.Add(_AutoCompleteListBox);
```

Вам нужно создать `UserControl`, на котором будут размещены `TextBox` и `ListBox`. А уже этот юзерконтрол помещать на форму.

---

В принципе, можно обойтись без юзерконтрола. Тогда нужно обращаться к свойству `Parent` текстбокса. Если текстбокс размещён прямо на форме, то родителем будет форма. Если он размещён на некоей панели, то, соответственно, родителем будет эта панель.

А далее помещаем листбокс на этот родительский контрол:

```
Parent.Controls.Add(_AutoCompleteListBox);
```

Но при этом нужны дополнительные проверки: что за родитель, есть ли на нём место, куда воткнуть листбокс и т. п. Ведь заранее неизвестно, где будет размещён ваш Custom TextBox.

Поэтому лучше и проще использовать юзерконтрол.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Очевидная ошибка и не менее очевидное решение. Благодарю.